# D3js-Get the first and the last decile

Tags: d3.js, scale, quantization

I have some data in a csv.
I want to get the first and the last decile of all the numbers.
I think I might need to use `d3.scale.quantize()` but I do not know how...

Thanks for your help I'm stuck since a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`d3.quantile()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_quantile) for this, i.e.

```
d3.quantile(numbers, 0.1);
d3.quantile(numbers, 0.9);
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AEH3n/).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get `numbers` from csv ? `d.aValue` ?
`function(d){return d.aValue;}`

Comment: That depends entirely on your application.